# Serial port baud rate change - getting "unable to perform all requested operation"

Tags: centos, tty, serial-port

I´m working under CentOS 7 distribution, I have worked with USB to serial converters and everithing works properly, but in this case I´m using a Versalogic MPEe-U2 board attached to a mini PCIe connector. I tested the functionality and it works fine but when I tried to change the baud rate I get the following error:

unable to perform all requested operation

Comment: Maybe the driver/device doesn't support the baud rate? FWIW, you need the new `TCSETS*2` ioctls to set arbitrary baud rates on Linux (which are not supported by glibc or stty, so you have to do it yourself in C, python, perl, etc.)

Comment: It is supposed that it supports the baud rate, I'm trying to change it from 115200 to 9600, according to the data sheet.